# PowerShell Connector for FIM 2010R2

Tags: powershell, azure

I am following the link [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640417(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640417%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

to configure the PowerShell Connector to synchronize my local AD server to Azure AD but I don't understand what "Server parameter" that the connector should connect to is.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I think it's your FIM server that should be placed as `server` parameter.

Comment: yeah, I got it works now, just put the domain name: For example xxx.onmicroft.com. Thanks